# Finding extremum of a function using Lagrange

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

$f(x, y) = \ln(x) + \ln(y) $
Restricted to $g(x, y) = x + y/2 - 1 = 0$

I did $\delta f(x, y) = \lambda \delta g(x, y) $

I have the system $1/x = \lambda$ and $1/y = \lambda /2$

But I'm stuck here. How to find lambda to find the critical points? Any help please

Comment: $2x=y$ once you solve for lambda in both equations and set them equal to each other. Finding lambda is almost never necessary in a Lagrange multipliers problem.

Comment: I didn't understand. Please could you show me how

Answer (score 2):

Your system is incomplete. It should be$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac1x=\lambda\\\frac1y=\frac\lambda2\\x+\frac y2-1=0.\end{array}\right.$$Its only solution is $(x,y,\lambda)=\left(\frac12,1,2\right)$.

Comment: And it is a maximum right?

Comment: Yes. The restriction of $f$ to the set of those $(x,y)$ such that $g(x,y)=0$ has a maximum at $\left(\frac12,1\right)$ and it has no minimum.

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely no need for Lagrange. As $x=1-y/2$ we have
$$
\ln(x)+\ln(y)=\ln(xy)=\ln\bigl((1-y/2)y\bigr).
$$
As $\ln$ is strictly monotone increasing and $(1-y/2)y$ takes it maximum for $y=1$ we're done: $x=1/2$ and the maximal value of $f$ is $\ln(1/2)$.